# How do I run a Python script from a subdirectory without breaking upper-level imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very simple scenario like this:

```
example/
    common.py
    folder1/
        script.py
```

where `script.py` file should import `common.py` module.

If I `cd` into `folder1/` and run the script (i.e. by calling `python3 script.py` on the command line), the import breaks with the usual error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'`.

I know I could turn the whole parent folder into a package by adding `__init__.py` files in each subdirectory, however this solution still prevents me to run the script directly from inside `folder1/`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to add a parent directory to the search path, you can always do:

```
import os
import sys

DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, DIR)
```

`os.path.realpath(__file__)` gets the realpath to the file, and `os.path.dirname` gets the directory name of this file. Doing it twice gets the `example` directory here. Now, since this is added to the search path, you can import `common`.

However, you should really consider having a dedicated `scripts` or `bin` directory, rather than try to run scripts from subdirectories. Think about writing a library, and import this library rather than individual files.

Comment: The OP _does_ have a dedicated scripts directory - and that's the whole problem. If it were convenient to put the scripts in the parent directory then `import common` would work just fine.

Answer (score 11):

If you turn both directories into python packages, and the top directory is in your PYTHONPATH, you can run script.py like so:

```sh
python3 -m example.folder1.script
```

Comment: This is the most clean way to run any script in any subfolder!